# How to display custom column in Customer component grid on condition?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have added a column to Customer Grid in customer_listing.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <actionsColumn name="order_as_customer" class="Foo\Bar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomColumnData">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
                <label translate="true">Title</label>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I have a field in system settings for determining whether a user wants to have the module enabled:

```
<field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
```

I want to display the column only if the user enables the module.

Is it possible to add customer_listing.xml override based on my condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add conditions to display custom columns in the grid component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="value">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Customer Custom Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```